# PopUp Notice : execute php script using jquery if new record added to mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i want do display information about new update from user. example :
this is url for user
example.com/user
and this is url for admin
example.com/admin

the proses is when user post the articel the admin is automatically get notice/information the notice is like this "1 New Post added" <- (popup dialog)

so, how to run the proces for admin. "when user post the admin is automatically get notice/information" about new added post using jquery?.

this is my file
**index.php**

```
<?php
include "popupnotice.php"
?>
```

**popupnotice.php**

```
<style type="text/css">
#popup {
    visibility: hidden; 
    background-color: red; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 100; 
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px
}
</style>
<div id="noticearea">
<?php
try{
$db = dbConn::getConnection();
$noinf= 'Y';
$sqlck = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id_notice) as idnotice FROM str_articel WHERE notice_info=:noinf");
$sqlck->bindParam(':noinf', $noinf);
$sqlck->execute();
$resck = $sqlck->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($resck)
{
?>
<div id="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="titlenotice"><h1>NOTICE/INFORMATION</h1></div>
                <div class="break"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="copy">
                <p>
<?php echo $resck['idnotice']; ?> New Post added
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="cf footer">
                <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>   
<?php }}
catch (PDOException $e) {
echo "Connection Error " . $e->getMessage();
} ?>
</div>
```

in default page index.php if i login and no new added post i do not get notice if new post is added to db and i get notice everytime if any new.

anyone can help?

Comment: you need to use setTimeout() in your main page with a function to call periodically the server. The server returns either 0 if no new posts or the popup if there are new posts.

Comment: any examples? sorry i was new about jquery..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User post goes to a database table user_post table
for admin, you have to do following things:

1. create a table new_post_update which has two field,one id,  reference id user_post.
2. refresh page at specified time interval using jQuery .

   ```
   $("document").ready(function(){
       var interval = setInterval(refresh_box(),60000);
       function refresh_box(){
           $("#myDiv").load('path/to/update.php');
       }
   }
   ```
3. update.php will update with all new post
4. call an AJAX and truncate the new_post_update table.
5. you can fetch all post from user_post any time and new post from new_post_update in time interval. Do it according to your coding